# JAX-RS URI matching using regex

Tags: regex, jax-rs

I defined the following two @PATH in JAX-RS:

```
@Path("{ontoId: [a-zA-Z0-9]+}/{version: [0-9]+}")
@GET
public String getSomething(){
      return "First";
}
@Path("{ontoId: [a-zA-Z0-9]+}/{version: [0-9]+}/{entity:#([a-zA-Z0-9]+)}")
@GET
public String getAnotherthing(){
      return "Second";
}
```

which cannot distinguish the following three Urls:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/pizza/20060718/#abcd
GET http://localhost:8080/pizza/20060718#abcd
GET http://localhost:8080/pizza/20060718
```

That is to say, all these three Urls will return "First".

What's wrong with my @Path definition?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW, would be good to state what JAX-RS implementation are you using.

Also note that '#' sign is not a valid URI path component character and is actually a delimiter for URI fragment component. As such it is not going to be parsed as part of JAX-RS request path matching algorithm. Essentially, in all those cases above only "20060718" is going to be matched (assuming "pizza" is your application context path).